# Dynamic service name with ocelot and consul

Tags: consul, service-discovery, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using Ocelot and API gateway with Consul and the service discovery.
I am registering services in the Consul with dynamic names like : service.name.1234 and service.name.5678

This services are statful and not meant to be scaled at all

Since i am working with Ocelot i would like to be able to route a request to the desired service but since the names are dynamic i would need to use the query string parameter as the service name

Example : http://myapp.com/service/1234
Should be redirected to the container with the name service.name.1234

Is there any way to achive this using both products? or maybe other product?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for myself for the same solution but found only one [comment](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/360#issuecomment-409600059) on GitHub and it helped me a lot

So, you need to create custom middleware that will rewrite Ocelot`s DownstreamRoute:

```
public static async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Func<Task> next)
    {
        
        var downstreamRoute = httpContext.Items.DownstreamRoute();

        var yourServiceName = //get query string parameter from httpContext;

        //rewrite any parameter that you want
        httpContext.Items.UpsertDownstreamRoute(
            new DownstreamRoute(
                downstreamRoute.Key,
                downstreamRoute.UpstreamPathTemplate,
                downstreamRoute.UpstreamHeadersFindAndReplace,
                downstreamRoute.DownstreamHeadersFindAndReplace,
                downstreamRoute.DownstreamAddresses,
                tenantServiceName,
                ...
            ));
    }
```

And after that call it in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // some other code

    var configuration = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
            {
                PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
                {
                    await RouteContextRetrieverMiddleware.InvokeAsync(ctx, next);

                    await next.Invoke();
                }
            };

            app.UseOcelot(configuration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: This works only for the first time for me as when I tried to switch it again to a new tenant, the downstream host did not change and continued to be the old tenant